# How to add an \n in txt when meet Specified word in python

Tags: python

I have a txt file (A.txt)with information like following:

```
 259 96 339 96 339 249 259 249 person 200 12 22 23 333 312 33 249 car
```

I want use python to modify this A.txt to something like that:

```
 259 96 339 96 339 249 259 249 person
 200 12 22 23 333 312 33 249 car
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8InR2.png)

Which means I have to add ('\n') after 'person' or 'car'.

I have difficulties about seek the word location, while the seek(n) can only seek  the position of characters.
And When I run the following code

```
 f.seek(0)
 f.write('\n')
```

It always add a new line in the end but not in the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we have the entire contents of the file in a string, we can use the simple replace method, as shown in the code below.

```
a = "259 96 339 96 339 249 259 249 person 200 12 22 23 333 312 33 249 car 12"
a = a.replace("person ", "person\n").replace("car ","car\n")
print(a)
```

The above code will display:

> 259 96 339 96 339 249 259 249 place
>
> 200 12 22 23 333 312 33 249 car
>
> 12

Comment: This seems to be the simplest solution!

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression is your friend here:

```
import re
string = "259 96 339 96 339 249 259 249 person 200 12 22 23 333 312 33 249 car"

rx = re.compile(r'\b(person|car)\s*')
string = rx.sub(r'\1\n', string)
print(string)
```

This yields

```
259 96 339 96 339 249 259 249 person
200 12 22 23 333 312 33 249 car
```

Comment: The regex is probably `\b(\w+)\b`

Comment: @AdamSmith: I had that first but you need to get rid of the whitespaces then.

Comment: True. `\b(\w+)\b\s*` then.

Comment: @AdamSmith: This makes the last word boundary useless (the `\w+\s*` automatically implies a word boundary).

Comment: Is that true? I think `\w+\s*` only implies a word boundary if it matches a non-zero number of spaces. Is there a word boundary between the last word and EOF? I actually don't know.

Comment: @AdamSmith: See https://regex101.com/r/Kpe3fL/1 and https://regex101.com/r/Kpe3fL/2, they match the exact same things. `\w+` is matching digits as well (`[0-9]`) so it won't help here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that should work on your entire text file. It will append a linebreak character to every word that follows a series of numbers.

```
import re

txt = r'259 96 339 96 339 249 259 249 person 200 12 22 23 333 312 33 249 car'
patt = r'\b[\d\s]+\w+\b'

found = re.findall(patt, txt)
outtxt = ''.join(['%s\n' % f.strip() for f in found])

>>>outtxt
259 96 339 96 339 249 259 249 person
200 12 22 23 333 312 33 249 car
```

Answer (score -1):

When

```py
import re
s = '259 96 339 96 339 249 259 249 person 200 12 22 23 333 312 33 249 car'
```

you can use str.**replace** (but it leaves spaces on begin of next line):

```py
print(s.replace('person', 'person\n').replace('car', 'car\n'))
```

Output (point at spaces on begin of next line). If you add space info replace pattern, the last occurrence of "person" or "car" will be not replaced.

```
259 96 339 96 339 249 259 249 person
 200 12 22 23 333 312 33 249 car
```

Or you can use **regular expression**:

```py
s = re.sub(r'\b(person|car)\b', r'\1\n', s)
```

Output.

```
259 96 339 96 339 249 259 249 person
200 12 22 23 333 312 33 249 car
```

Or more general, you can replace **all words** after digit and space:

```py
s = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)(\s+[a-z]+)\b *', r'\1\n', s)
```

The same output.

*EDIT: Reedited, preset (`re` and `s`) added, output added, print added.*